# What miner can I use to mine litecoin with the scrypt hash function?

Tags: litecoin, gpu

When I run cgminer for run it to mine ltc the parameter --scrypt, cgminer says that is not recognized option. So, cgminer does not work.

What miner can I use to mine litecoin with the scrypt hash function?

Comment: `cgminer` does not support scrypt mining, this was removed a long time ago.

Comment: what miner can i use for litecoin that you reccomend @Bitcoin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at [this table of software scrypt miners](https://litecoin.info/Mining_software).

You don't mention whether you intend to try to use a CPU or GPU to mine. Towards the top of the list is sgminer (for GPU mining) and Pooler's cpuminer (for CPU mining). There are other choices listed there, but a number of them are just graphical frontends or are listed as no longer maintained.

Comment: thanks Joseph you think is best gpu or cpu mine for litecoin?

Comment: Well, if you have a GPU it should be better than a CPU in terms of how much hashing power it has. You can use a [Litecoin mining calculator](http://litecoinminingcalculator.com/) (that was just the first one that appeared on Google) and put in the hash rate, which you would get from the mining software when you try using it. That way you can figure out how much litecoins you can expect to receive.